# CQ5 Spring integration

Tags: spring, architecture, inversion-of-control, aem

Is the any way to perform integration CQ5 platform with Spring framework?
I would like to use Spring IoC capabilities to make my code more clear and efficient.

UPDATE

Hello againg, seems that I found solution.
Guys here developed [Slice framework](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/make-your-cq-life-easier-with-slice/) that really redices amound of code and made CQ5 development easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to check out [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/), or it's original incarnation [Spring Dynamic Modules](http://www.springsource.org/osgi).  The Blueprint project basically gives you an easy way to create Spring enabled bundles in an OSGi environment.

As shsteimer mentions, [Spring distributions before 3.2.0 were OSGi bundles](http://www.springsource.org/springframework-ebr), so could be dropped into an OSGi environment and you could probably use them directly.  Spring 3.2.0 bundles and above are now available through the [SpringSource ERB](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle?query=S).  However, Blueprint gets around or helps with some of the boilerplate OSGi stuff that you would otherwise have to do.

Answer (score 1):

On a past project, I was able to get Spring JDBC working inside of CQ (to support some legacy code so we didn't have to re-write it).  My memory is that the spring jar files already come "OSGI-ified" and so it was just a matter of figuring out all the layers of dependency needed for JDBC to work inside of CQ, and adding all the jars to the repository in an /apps/myApp/install folder.

Long story short, I'm not sure about IoC, but you might check to see if it's already packaged as an OSGI version which you can simply use without too much hassle.